# How to determine the total number of files in folder & subfolders, by extension?

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

How could one transverse through a folder and its subfolders (directory and its subdirectories) and list how many files of a certain extension there is in those in total, for every extension that occurs in those folders?

Something similar to this,

```
folders               48 total
.jpg                2842 total
.gif                 142 total
.CR2                2842 total
```

The sum of above should be the same as the total in `dir/s` which lists all files & subfolders in some folder.

Comment: I noticed one of the close votes was listed as "too broad". It would help if the voter explained on what aspects the question could be improved in that respect, that is - what was unclear about it? How to determine the total number of folders and files of that and that ... extension in some folder and its subfolders, in Windows 7 cmd? Seems a relatively precise question to me. I do not know in what respects it could be further defined.

Comment: "and so on, for every extension". You haven't defined **every extension**. Do you mean every unique extension on the whole disk? All registered extensions? A list of extension in a file? Something else?

Comment: Are you looking for a complete solution? What have you tried so far? Where is the script you have tried? etc ....

Comment: @DavidPostill - Just extensions which appear in folder in question and its subfolders.

Comment: @DavidPostill - I've been doing it slowly & manually; dir/s for total number of files and then listing all jpgs, then listing all gifs, then all CR2s and so on. But for a large number of files and extensions this is a very slow and tiresome process, prone to error.

Comment: That's still not clear. What if an extension is in the sub-folder and not the root folder?

Comment: @DavidPostill - How do you mean? I wish to transverse through a folder and its subfolders (directory and its subdirectories, if you prefer that terminology) and list how many files of a certain extension there is in there in total, and so on for every extension there exists in that directory and its subdirectories. If one file of a certain extension (say, .txt) appears in some subdirectory but not in root folder, then list it as *.txt - 1 file or alike.

Comment: Ok. Took me about an hour. See my answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't need to be commandline you can use WinDirStat.http://windirstat.info/download.html[image]

Answer (score 1):

Next code snippet could help:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
rem EnableDelayedExpansion
rem next line: clear/delete all `_filesTotal` environment variables
for /F "delims==" %%G in ('set _filesTotal 2^>NUL') do set "%%G="
rem next line: initialize `_foldersTotal` environment variable
set "_foldersTotal=0"
pushd "folder where count"
for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir /B /S /A') do (
  if exist "%%~G\" (
    rem folder %%G
    set /A "_foldersTotal+=1"
  ) else (
    rem   file %%G
    if "%%~xG"=="" (set /A "_filesTotal.+=1") else (set /A "_filesTotal%%~xG+=1")
  )
)
rem next two lines: display raw results
echo %CD%
set _foldersTotal
set _filesTotal
popd
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`>>`, `2>NUL` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Comment: Thank you JosefZ. The .bat is giving me some errors so I'm currently trying to modify it to work properly.

Comment: Yes, `set /A "_filesTotal%%~xG+=1"` could return `Missing operator.` error if file extension contains any character which is an [operator in `set /A` command](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) like `~`, `+`, `-` etc.

Comment: @JosefZ Hmm. My solution matches the number of .txt files I have correctly. Your solution finds 2 fewer. I've no idea why :/

Comment: @DavidPostill Haha:) On _my_ test data `_filesTotal.txt=189` vs. **your** solution finds 1 fewer `.txt 188 total`. Both seem to be exact: `dir /S /A *.txt` gives recapitulation `189 File(s)` while `dir /S *.txt` recapitulates `188 File(s)`. There is one hidden file counted in my solution. However, I can't imagine the contrary scenario as `dir /B /A *.txt` should always give _more_ lines than `dir /B *.txt`.

Comment: Hmm. I have no hidden files. I still don't see why there should be a difference :( Unless we can figure out which files are miscounted.

Comment: @DavidPostill Could you compare `dir /S /A *.txt` and `dir /S *.txt` recapitulation please (or whole output of 19 files).

Comment: Exactly the same output `19 File(s) 750,609 bytes`

Comment: http://imgur.com/owtU67h

Comment: @DavidPostill I have disabled `8.3` names on my disk so `dir /s *.txt` does not show fake matches `chines.txt1` and  `chinese.txt1`. That's the difference!

Comment: @JosefZ Ah. Well spotted. Do you know if there is an (easy) solution to account for that an a batch file? I will update my answer to make a note anyway (until I figure out a workaround). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I urge you to consider a Powershell approach to your question.  It’s slightly less lines of code with the ability to sort the output…

```
$foldercount = 0
$hash = @{}
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Code Samples" -Recurse | ForEach-Object { 
    if ($_.Attributes -eq 'Directory') 
        { 
        ++$foldercount
        }
    else
        {
        if ($hash.ContainsKey($_.Extension)) 
            { $count = $hash.Get_Item($_.Extension); ++$count; $hash.Set_Item($_.Extension, $count) }
        else
            { $hash.Add($_.Extension, 1) } 
        }
}

Write-Host $foldercount folders
$hash.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Value -descending
```

And, produces this output for my sample folder...

```
90 folders

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                 
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                 
.tlog                          186                                                                                                                                                                                                   
.h                             72                                                                                                                                                                                                    
.obj                           56                                                                                                                                                                                                    
.cpp                           54                                                                                                                                                                                                    
.pdb                           26                                                                                                                                                                                                    
.manifest                      24                                                                                                                                                                                                    
.res                           23                                                                                                                                                                                                    
.rc                            22                                                                                                                                                                                                    
.log                           15                                                                                                                                                                                                    
.lastbuildstate                12                                                                                                                                                                                                    
.ipch                          12                                                                                                                                                                                                    
.ico                           12                                                                                                                                                                                                    
.exe                           12                                                                                                                                                                                                    
.idb                           12                                                                                                                                                                                                    
.vcxproj                       11                                                                                                                                                                                                    
.ilk                           11                                                                                                                                                                                                    
.user                          11                                                                                                                                                                                                    
.sdf                           11                                                                                                                                                                                                    
.zip                           11                                                                                                                                                                                                    
.filters                       11                                                                                                                                                                                                    
.sln                           11                                                                                                                                                                                                    
.pch                           11                                                                                                                                                                                                    
.txt                           8                                                                                                                                                                                                     
.gif                           8                                                                                                                                                                                                     
.rc2                           8                                                                                                                                                                                                     
.aps                           8                                                                                                                                                                                                     
.bmp                           7                                                                                                                                                                                                     
.dsw                           6                                                                                                                                                                                                     
.dsp                           6                                                                                                                                                                                                     
.png                           5                                                                                                                                                                                                     
.css                           5                                                                                                                                                                                                     
.html                          4                                                                                                                                                                                                     
.old                           4                                                                                                                                                                                                     
.XML                           4                                                                                                                                                                                                     
.vcproj                        4                                                                                                                                                                                                     
.xslt                          4                                                                                                                                                                                                     
.exp                           3                                                                                                                                                                                                     
.dll                           3                                                                                                                                                                                                     
.lib                           3                                                                                                                                                                                                     
.clw                           2                                                                                                                                                                                                     
.def                           2                                                                                                                                                                                                     
.opt                           2                                                                                                                                                                                                     
.ncb                           2                                                                                                                                                                                                     
.plg                           2                                                                                                                                                                                                     
.recipe                        2                                                                                                                                                                                                     
.rtf                           1                                                                                                                                                                                                     
.jpg                           1                                                                                                                                                                                                     
.h original                    1                                                                                                                                                                                                     
.bat                           1                                                                                                                                                                                                     
.js                            1                                                                                                                                                                                                     
.cpp original                  1                                                                                                                                                                                                     
.DPbcd                         1
```

Comment: On my box, it shows `0 folders` and all _folders_ counts among files. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @JosefZ Did you change the path name?

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\bat\files" -Recurse | ForEach-Object {` of course

Comment: @JosefZ I'm using Powershell 4.0.  You should probably check your version.

Comment: `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` returns `Major  Minor  Build  Revision` as follows: `4      0      -1     -1`

Comment: @JosefZ Sorry...I'm at a loss.  I tried it with a sub-folder off the original sample path and it worked fine.  Maybe you should step through the sample in the ISE.

Comment: It's because my folders `.Attributes` are `Directory, NotContentIndexed`. Change `-eq`comparison operator to `-like` as follows: `if ($_.Attributes -like '*Directory*')` .

Comment: Works, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

#### Traversing folders and counting files

> How could one transverse through a folder and its subfolders (directory and its subdirectories) and list how many files of a certain extension there is in those in total, for every extension that occurs in those folders?

Use the following 3 batch files.

Notes:

- Currently does not count files with no extension (that appeared to be outside of the brief in the question).
- Some files may be counted multiple times if 8.3 names are **not** disabled.

**Total.cmd**:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem count directories
call CountDirs
rem get list of extensions
for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`dir /a:-d /b /s`) do (
  set _extension=%%~xi
  if [!_extension!] neq [] echo !_extension:~1! >> %temp%\extensions 
  )
rem get list of unique extensions
set _last=
for /f "usebackq" %%j in (`sort %temp%\extensions`) do (
  set _this=%%j
  if [!_last!] neq [!_this!] echo !_this! >> %temp%\unique
  set _last=%%j
  )
rem count the files
for /f %%k in (%temp%\unique) do (
  call CountFiles %%k
  )
rem cleanup
if exist %temp%\extensions del %temp%\extensions
if exist %temp%\unique del %temp%\unique
endlocal
```

**CountDirs.cmd**:

```
@echo off
rem count directories
dir /a:d /b /s | find "" /c /v > %temp%\count
set /p _count=<%temp%\count
rem cleanup
del %temp%\count
echo folders %_count% total
```

**CountFiles.cmd**:

```
@echo off
rem count files matching %1
dir /b *.%1 /s 2> nul | find "" /v /c > %temp%\count
set /p _count=<%temp%\count
rem cleanup
del %temp%\count
echo .%1 %_count% total
```

**Example output**:

```
F:\test>Total.cmd
folders 15 total
.1 1 total
.bat 1 total
.cmd 10 total
.csv 6 total
.exe 4 total
.html 1 total
.java 1 total
.jpg 1 total
.js 1 total
.mak 1 total
.php 1 total
.ps1 1 total
.sh 1 total
.txt 19 total
.txt1 2 total
.zip 1 total
F:\test>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [if](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) - Conditionally perform a command.
- [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) - A command line argument (or parameter) is any value passed into a batch script.
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple and efficient approach
`find . -type f | sed -n 's/..*\.//p' | sort | uniq -c`

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.